# syntax error in mysql 'trigger'

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am just trying to use trigger instead of check constraint and code one but it gives me an error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER conflict 
ON roozane 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if rDate = NEW.rDate then
if NEW.rStartTime < rStartTime AND NEW.rEndTime < rEndTime then
INSERT INTO roozane (rID,rDate,rStartTime,rEndTime,rPlace,rComment,rType) values (NEW.rID,NEW.rDate,NEW.rStartTime,NEW.rEndTime,NEW.rPlace,NEW.rComment,NEW.rType);
end if
end if
END;$$
```

And error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON roozane FOR EACH ROW BEGIN if ( rDate=NEW.rDate ) then if ( NEW.rStart' at line 2
```

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TRIGGER conflict BEFORE INSERT
ON roozane 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if rDate = NEW.rDate then
if NEW.rStartTime < rStartTime AND NEW.rEndTime < rEndTime then
INSERT INTO roozane (rID,rDate,rStartTime,rEndTime,rPlace,rComment,rType) values (NEW.rID,NEW.rDate,NEW.rStartTime,NEW.rEndTime,NEW.rPlace,NEW.rComment,NEW.rType);
end if
end if
END;$$
```

and the error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
```

tnx for help

Comment: Where is your *trigger_time* and *trigger_event*?

`CREATE TRIGGER conflict
BEFORE UPDATE
ON roozane`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: yea fixed tnx but now it forwarded to INSERT command and here show syntax error

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your last comment. Could you please post your updated query and the error?

Answer (score 1):

You need a *trigger_time* and *trigger_event*. For example:
`CREATE TRIGGER conflict AFTER INSERT`

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon after each `end if` to terminate those compound statements.

You don't need a semicolon after the last `END`, because presumably you have used `DELIMITER $$` to change the statement terminator in the mysql client.

I tested the following.  It did not get a syntax error, but of course I have no table called `roozane` so I got a different error.  :-)

```
CREATE TRIGGER conflict BEFORE INSERT
ON roozane 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
if rDate = NEW.rDate then
if NEW.rStartTime < rStartTime AND NEW.rEndTime < rEndTime then
INSERT INTO roozane (rID,rDate,rStartTime,rEndTime,rPlace,rComment,rType) values (NEW.rID,NEW.rDate,NEW.rStartTime,NEW.rEndTime,NEW.rPlace,NEW.rComment,NEW.rType);
end if;
end if;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your trigger.

As far as syntactical and logic errors go

1. Looking at the error message apparently you didn't use `DELIMITER $$` at the beggining of your script.
2. You have three undeclared variables in your trigger `rDate`, `rStartTime`, `rEndTime`. If you use stored procedure level variables you need to declare them first and eventually assign  values to them.
3. As @BillKarwin mentioned in his answer you have to have semicolons at the end of each `IF ... END IF;` statement and you don't need semicolon after closing `END` of a `BEGIN...END` block of your trigger since you should've changed `DELIMITER` earlier to `$$`.

That being said syntactically correct version of your trigger might be following

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER conflict 
BEFORE INSERT ON roozane 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE rDate      DATE;
  DECLARE rStartTime TIME;
  DECLARE rEndTime   TIME;

  IF rDate = NEW.rDate THEN
    IF NEW.rStartTime < rStartTime AND NEW.rEndTime < rEndTime THEN
        INSERT INTO roozane (rID,rDate,rStartTime,rEndTime,rPlace,rComment,rType)
        VALUES(NEW.rID,NEW.rDate,NEW.rStartTime,NEW.rEndTime,NEW.rPlace,NEW.rComment,NEW.rType);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END$$
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb589/1)** demo that shows that now your trigger is being successfully created **but does nothing** since declared variables by default have values of `NULL` and other values have not been assigned to them.

Here goes **the most important part**: event if the problem with the variables will be fixed unfortunately your trigger **won't work** anyway because MySql with its rather limited support for triggers doesn't allow data manipulation statements (`INSERT` in your case) on the same table (`roozane` in your case) you are attaching your trigger to.

***Now, to help you to fix your trigger you need to explain what you want your trigger to check for.***